# Configuring google Cloud Load balancer and managed SSL without downtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openssl, ssl-certificate, cpanel, google-cloud-load-balancer

**objective:** Moving a website to Google Cloud with a load balancer using Google's managed SSL without downtime.

**current configuration:**

- A Google Load Balancer with unmanaged instance group that currently has 1 VM.
- The website is using a cpanel which I have access to update the DNS settings.
- The domain has a wildcare positiveSSL certificate.
- The website is also using cloudfront SSL.

**Problem:** The main issue I have is configuring and provisioning SSL.

Mentally, before making the move, I'm thinking it should be a breeze. No.....!

**Situation:**

- I set up the load balancer but it can't provision the SSL because the domain is using positiveSSL on another server.

I read that I need to have a A record pointed to the load balancer in order for it to provision. I also read that for cpanel, if I were to make any changes to the A record, it will affect the mail service. I don't want the mail services to be disrupted.

- I tried adding a new A record pointing to the load balancer's IP but it doesn't allow because the current A record is using Alias pointing to cloudfront's and I have to detach them first. I don't think this is a good move.
- My planned ideal steps are to ensure the load balancer is functioning properly and pointing to the website correctly before I update the DNS.

I'm not sure if this approach makes sense technically, I set up a A record for a random subdomain to point to the load balancer's IP, the provisioning is successful but it returns an error

```
curl: (35) error:14084210:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

How should I go about doing it? I didn't know switching a server is so difficult.

Comment: You will have downtime to set up a load balancer and SSL certificate. If downtime is critical, practice with a test domain first. This answer will help you minimize downtime: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68386511/8016720

Answer (score 0):

Discard the wildcare SSL and cloudfront SSL from your domain and provision a google managed SSL instead.But before that, you need to create a [managed zone](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/zones) in cloud DNS  add your website as A record there pointing to server’s IP address, only then you will be able to provision SSL. It might require a little downtime which you can reduce using tactics mentioned in John’s link.
Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/records) for help in managing cloud DNS records.
Refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs) for help in provisioning google managed SSL certificates.